# how could I call privileged(need administrator privilege) programs from normal privileged programs?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run a child process that requires elevation and wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893262/how-can-i-run-a-child-process-that-requires-elevation-and-wait)

CreateProcess does not works, the UAC dialog does not even show up.

Comment: That, and far too vague.What is thr return value and error reported by `CreateProcess()`? You'll probably find it's "Elevation required" which means you need to use `ShellExecute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, the easiest method is this; under project properties, under Linker section set "UAC Execution Level" to requireAdministrator.
You can manually create a manifest file if you are using another build environment.