# Run System( ) CMD commands with Admin rights

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find a way to run CMD commands as Administrator in my C++ code.

i.e:

```
system("taskkill /im mygame.exe");
```

This won't work and it will pop up an "Error: Access Denied" Message.
If I run Windows CMD as Admin and execute the same command directly, it will work perfectly.

So what would be a way to use CMD as Administrator automatically in C++?

I've read some other threads on here but nothing I can directly relate/ get from them.

Examples are very appreciated.

Comment: Not quite sure in Windows, but I suppose you need to run your application in Admin rights, have a try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a child process that requires elevation and wait?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893262/how-can-i-run-a-child-process-that-requires-elevation-and-wait)

Comment: @MrEricSir I don't see how that thread relates to my question/ would solve my problem, might be because I'm new to C++ and need a simpler answer that relates more to my specific case or other insights on this topic.

Comment: We may note that the other question is not a duplicate; he needs to elevate something that isn't manifested for elevation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to launch via a helper EXE manifested with requireAdministrator.

Your helper program reads:

```
#include <process.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
    return _spawnve(_P_WAIT, argv[1], argv + 1, env);
}
```

You will not be able to start your own child process with CreateProcess or system(). You must start the helper program with:

```
ShellExecute(hwnd, "helper.exe", "whatever you were going to pass to system()", NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Where hwnd is some window you have (pass NULL if you have no visible window).

Ref1: [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Ref2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Ref3: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I actually didn't get anything about the code you just wrote (as I said I'm basically new to this) but I did find an easier way (in case anyone goes through the same in the future). In Visual Studio C++, go to Project > Project Property > Linker > Manifest File > and set UAC Administration level to > Require Administration. This will ask for Admin rights every time you open the .exe file (and execute the System( ) commands as Admin as well.

Comment: Which does work of course, but not the question asked. Nevertheless, go for it.

Answer (score -2):

The usual way would be to use `runas`:

```
system("runas /user:Administrator@domain \"taskkill /im mygame.exe\"");
```

Comment: @ChrisDood Hi, sadly this won't work. even though the program asks me for the Admin's password, it will still display the same error afterwards (Access Denied).