# how to run command on admin command prompt through c++ program

Tags: c++, windows

How to run command on command prompt as admin through c++ program. I used `ShellExecute(),` but it does not run command on command prompt as admin.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\vss\\vshadow-2008-x64.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

And how to capture the output from the command prompt as admin to the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a child process that requires elevation and wait?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893262/how-can-i-run-a-child-process-that-requires-elevation-and-wait)

Comment: @DJ: probably not, as the other OP didn't need the output from the child process, which significantly complicates things.  (I have a feeling there *is* a duplicate somewhere, though.)